# flatten from mathematica to matlab

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica, flatten

how can i write this command from mathematica to matlab?

```
total = Apply[Plus, Flatten[mlat]]/L2
```

,where L2 is a value and mlat a matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply write:

```
 total = sum(mlat(:)) / L2
```

Comment: It supposes to give me one number as result,not a matrix. (mlat=2*round(rand(L,L))-1)

Comment: `Apply[Plus,list]` is the sum of elements in `list`, so use `sum`

Comment: sorry, as yaroslav said, just sum() what I wrote, so sum(mlat(:)/L2)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.In order to take one value ,i have to do mlat(:),so If i have "Apply[Plus,mlat]" i do "sum(mlat(:))" right? If i have "Apply[Plus,Flatten(mlat)]" what must i do?

Comment: Ok,thanks,so if i have Apply[Plus,list] -->> sum(list)       and if i have  Apply[Plus,Flatten[list]]  --... sum(list(:))

Answer (score 1):

No help for matlab, but in Mathematica you may simply write

```
total = Total[mlat, -1]/L2
```

in place of

```
total = Apply[Plus, Flatten[mlat]]/L2
```

Comment: Ok,thanks.But i think in my example the "2" in Total[mlat,2] must not exist if i understood it well.

Comment: @George I assumed that `mlat` is a two-dimensional array, not a tensor of greater depth, or a simple vector.  In the original version, `Flatten[mlat]` creates a vector of all elements in array mlat, and `Apply[Plus, ...]` gives the sum of the elements of that vector.  `Total[mlat, 2]` gives the sum of `mlat` down to level 2, in other words the sum of all elements in `mlat`.  Therefore, for a two-dimensional array `mlat`, the outputs should be the same.

Comment: @George I occurs to me that a better substitution would be `Total[mlat, -1]/L2` because this means total all levels of `mlat` and will work the same as Flatten even if `mlat` is a vector or tensor.  I am sorry I cannot help with Matlab as I never use it, but I am happy to help explain any Mathematica code you need to translate.  I do not know if there is a private message feature of this website; I am a new member to StackOverflow.